# Grouping pandas DataFrame by 10 minute intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

Given the following pandas dataframe:

```
            timestamp
0     2018-10-05 23:07:02
1     2018-10-05 23:07:13
2     2018-10-05 23:07:23
3     2018-10-05 23:07:36
4     2018-10-05 23:08:02
5     2018-10-05 23:09:16
6     2018-10-05 23:09:21
7     2018-10-05 23:09:39
8     2018-10-05 23:09:47
9     2018-10-05 23:10:01
10    2018-10-05 23:10:11
11    2018-10-05 23:10:23
12    2018-10-05 23:10:59
13    2018-10-05 23:11:03
14    2018-10-08 03:35:32
15    2018-10-08 03:35:58
16    2018-10-08 03:37:16
17    2018-10-08 03:38:04
18    2018-10-08 03:38:30
19    2018-10-08 03:38:36
20    2018-10-08 03:38:42
21    2018-10-08 03:38:52
22    2018-10-08 03:38:57
23    2018-10-08 03:39:10
24    2018-10-08 03:39:27
25    2018-10-08 03:40:47
26    2018-10-08 03:40:54
27    2018-10-08 03:41:02
28    2018-10-08 03:41:12
29    2018-10-08 03:41:32
```

How can I label in periods of ten minutes each rows? For example:

```
            timestamp       10min_period
0     2018-10-05 23:07:02   period_1
2     2018-10-05 23:07:23   period_1
1     2018-10-05 23:07:13   period_1
2     2018-10-05 23:07:23   period_1
3     2018-10-05 23:07:36   period_1
4     2018-10-05 23:08:02   period_1
5     2018-10-05 23:09:16   period_1
6     2018-10-05 23:09:21   period_1
7     2018-10-05 23:09:39   period_1
8     2018-10-05 23:09:47   period_1
9     2018-10-05 23:10:01   period_1
10    2018-10-05 23:10:11   period_1
11    2018-10-05 23:10:23   period_1
12    2018-10-05 23:10:59   period_1
13    2018-10-05 23:11:03   period_1
14    2018-10-08 03:35:32   period_2
15    2018-10-08 03:35:58   period_2
16    2018-10-08 03:37:16   period_2
17    2018-10-08 03:38:04   period_2
18    2018-10-08 03:38:30   period_2
19    2018-10-08 03:38:36   period_2
20    2018-10-08 03:38:42   period_2
21    2018-10-08 03:38:52   period_2
22    2018-10-08 03:38:57   period_2
23    2018-10-08 03:39:10   period_2
24    2018-10-08 03:39:27   period_2
25    2018-10-08 03:40:47   period_2
26    2018-10-08 04:40:54   period_3
27    2018-10-08 04:41:02   period_3
28    2018-10-08 04:41:12   period_3
29    2018-10-08 04:41:32   period_3
```

As you can see in the above expected output, each `period_n` label is created by counting 10 minutes periods of time, when the datetime series exceeds a threshold of ten minutes a new label is created. I tried to use the `dt.floor(10Min)` object, however, its not working because it doesnt keep track of where to start and where to end counting the periods of 10 minutes. Also I tried to:

`a = df['timestamp'].offsets.DateOffset(minutes=10)`

However, its not working. Any idea of how to segment my DF in periods of 10 minutes? This question is different from others because I am not specifying any particular time to start to count. That is, I start to count from the first datetime row instance, and from that I start to count the periods of ten time minutes.

UPDATE:

After transforming to datetime object, I also tried to

`df['timestamp'].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min'))`

However, I got:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Comment: please look at the answer you've accepted, it isn't even correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
diffs = df['timestamp'] - df['timestamp'].shift()
laps = diffs > pd.Timedelta('10 min')
periods = laps.cumsum().apply(lambda x: 'period_{}'.format(x+1))
df['10min_period'] = periods
```

Comment: This answer is not correct, and does not do what OP expected. The objective is to group by ten minute intervals, not assign labels based on the difference.

Answer (score 4):

With a little vectorised arithmetic, this should be possible (and be performant):

```
# Convert to datetime if not already.
# df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce')    
u = (df.assign(timestamp=df['timestamp'].dt.floor('20min'))
       .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='10min'))
       .ngroup())

df['10min_period'] = np.char.add('period_', (pd.factorize(u)[0] + 1).astype(str))
```

Unfortunately, the drawback here is that, while this will produce the expected output for your sample data, there is no easy way to handle contiguous intervals of 10 minutes (`pd.Grouper` does not begin grouping from the first date in your column, so the `dt.floor('20min')` is necessary as an initial step—this will inadvertently lump in some—or most—rows from "period_{i+1}" under "period_{i}").

Comment: Thanks for the help however, If you check the expected output the period_2 starts on row number 14, not 9. The reason is that the period starts at 23:07:02 and ends at  23:11:03 (less than 10 minutes)

Comment: check @ghilas answer, is there any other way to get the same result with factorize? I think this one is more elegant

Comment: @anon Ghilas answer is more incorrect because it increments counts based on the first difference over 10 minutes, instead of grouping every 10 minutes. Not sure why you've accepted it and are using it.

Comment: If you start counting from `2018-10-05 23: 07: 02` to` 2018-10-05 23: 11: 03` you can see that about 5 minutes passed. If you look at the next row, that is `2018-10-08 03: 35: 32`, you can notice that there is a jump greater than 10 minutes therefore a new period of time starts to be counted. That is, from `2018-10-08 03: 35: 32` until `2018-10-08 03: 40: 47` the rows are assigned to new period (period_2) due to the fact that the next position 2018 -10-08 04: 40: 54` exceeds the lapse of 10 minutes. I think that the factorize method its very elegant... Is there a way of doing it with it?

Comment: @anon Factorize was only to re-label already labelled rows. I have provided a slightly different alternative (similar to the other answer, but a little more performant).

Comment: Thanks for the effort and your time, Im checking it!

Comment: This is almost correct. However, for instance, check: https://pastebin.com/8smX3TgP you can see that just one period was assigned. However, its wrong because overall 12.93 minutes elapsed. Therefore, there should be two groups.

Answer (score 2):

For reproduce your problem I do this:

```
index = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(10), periods=100, freq='min')
```

This way I have this DataFrame:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(index)
a
                     0
0  2018-10-28 00:00:00
1  2018-10-28 00:01:00
2  2018-10-28 00:02:00
3  2018-10-28 00:03:00
4  2018-10-28 00:04:00
5  2018-10-28 00:05:00
6  2018-10-28 00:06:00
7  2018-10-28 00:07:00
8  2018-10-28 00:08:00
9  2018-10-28 00:09:00
10 2018-10-28 00:10:00
                   ...
[100 rows x 1 columns]
```

Then, I do this:

```
a['period'] = a.apply(lambda x: "perdio_%d"%(int(x[0].minute/10) + 1), axis=1)
```

And I have this solution:

```
                     0    period
0  2018-10-28 00:00:00  perdio_1
1  2018-10-28 00:01:00  perdio_1
2  2018-10-28 00:02:00  perdio_1
3  2018-10-28 00:03:00  perdio_1
4  2018-10-28 00:04:00  perdio_1
5  2018-10-28 00:05:00  perdio_1
6  2018-10-28 00:06:00  perdio_1
7  2018-10-28 00:07:00  perdio_1
8  2018-10-28 00:08:00  perdio_1
9  2018-10-28 00:09:00  perdio_1
10 2018-10-28 00:10:00  perdio_2
11 2018-10-28 00:11:00  perdio_2
12 2018-10-28 00:12:00  perdio_2
13 2018-10-28 00:13:00  perdio_2
14 2018-10-28 00:14:00  perdio_2
15 2018-10-28 00:15:00  perdio_2
                             ...
```

I hope it has been helpfull

Answer (score 1):

I have saved your dataframe in Notepad and called it `timestamp.txt`. It looks like this in Notepad:
[image]

And then I wrote this simple code:

```
import pandas as pd

timestamp = pd.read_csv("C:\\...path_of_your_file...\\timestamp.txt")  # read file
timestamp['10_Minute_Period'] = 0  # add column and initilize it to zero
numb_groups = int((timestamp.shape[0])/10)  # calculate number of groups
groups = 1  # initialize number of groups to one

while groups <= numb_groups+1:
   for idx, _ in timestamp.iterrows():  # iterate over row indexes
       # check if current row is below the group and the value is equal to 0
       if idx < groups*10 and timestamp.at[idx,'10_Minute_Period'] == 0:
           # in this case, write corresponding Period
           timestamp.loc[idx,'10_Minute_Period'] = ('Period' + str(groups))
   groups += 1  # increment groups and check while condition

print(timestamp)  # print the final modified timestamp
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help!