# pandas aggregation based on timestamp threshold

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I hope somebody can help me to solve this issue.

I have a csv file structured as follow:

[image]

I am trying to group the events based on `message`, `name`, `userID` if the events manifests in a 10min threshold starting from the first event matched.

the output I am expecting from the csv, is to see only 3 rows, because the second and third (as they are in 10min threshold and the message and name and ID are the same, they should be grouped) and have an extra columns name `event_count` that report how many time that event occurred.like this

[image]

I start working on this and my script looks like this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# 0. sort data by timestamp if not already sorted
file_csv = 'test.csv'
f = pd.read_csv(file_csv)
f['@timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(f['@timestamp'])
f = f.sort_values('@timestamp')

# lazy groupby
groups = f.groupby(['message','name','userID'])

# 1. compute the time differences `timediff` and compare to threshold
f['timediff'] = groups['@timestamp'].diff() < pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)

# 2. find the blocks with cumsum
f['event_count'] = groups['timediff'].cumsum()

# 3. groupby the blocks
out = (f.groupby(['message','name', 'userID'])
       .agg({'@timestamp':'first', 'timediff':'count'})
       )



keep_col = ['@timestamp', 'message', 'name', 'userID', 'event_count']
new_f = f[keep_col]
new_f.to_csv("aggregationtest.csv", index=False)
```

But the aggregation is totally wrong because is grouping all the event together even if they don't fall in the 10min threshold.

I am really struggling to understand what I am doing wrong if somebody can help me to understand the issue

UPDATE:

After some testing I managed to get a closer output to what I am expecting but still wrong.

I did some updated on the out variable as follow

```
out = (f.groupby(['message','name', 'userID', 'timediff']).agg({'@timestamp':'first','message': 'unique','name': 'unique', 'userID': 'unique', 'timediff': 'count'}))
```

This bit of code now produce an output that looks like:

[image]

But even if its grouping now, the count is wrong. Having this csv file

```
@timestamp,message,name,userID
2021-07-13 21:36:18,Failed to download file,Failed to download file,admin
2021-07-14 03:46:16,Successful Logon for user "user1",Logon Attempt,1
2021-07-14 03:51:16,Successful Logon for user "user1",Logon Attempt,1
2021-07-14 03:54:16,Successful Logon for user "user1",Logon Attempt,1
2021-07-14 04:55:16,Successful Logon for user "user1",Logon Attempt,1
```

I am expecting to have the following event_count

```
1
3
1
```

But I am getting different out come.

Comment: Please post a sample of your csv file in plain text so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I updated my post with the csv in plain text. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to somehow identify the different periods within the groups. The solution below gives each period within the group a name, which can then be included in the `groupby` that generates the count:

```
import pandas as pd

file_csv = 'test.csv'
f = pd.read_csv(file_csv)
f['@timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(f['@timestamp'])
f = f.sort_values('@timestamp')

def check(item): #taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53189777/11380795
    diffs = item - item.shift()
    laps = diffs > pd.Timedelta('10 min')
    periods = laps.cumsum().apply(lambda x: 'period_{}'.format(x+1))
    return periods

#create period names 
f['period'] = f.groupby(['message','name','userID'])['@timestamp'].transform(check)
#groupby and count
(f.groupby(['message','name', 'userID', 'period']).agg({'@timestamp':'first', 'period': 'count'})).rename(columns={"period": "timediff"}).reset_index()
```

Output:

|  | message | name | userID | period | @timestamp | timediff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Failed to download file | Failed to download file | admin | period_1 | 2021-07-13 21:36:18 | 1 |
| 1 | Successful Logon for user "user1" | Logon Attempt | 1 | period_1 | 2021-07-14 03:46:16 | 3 |
| 2 | Successful Logon for user "user1" | Logon Attempt | 1 | period_2 | 2021-07-14 04:55:16 | 1 |

Comment: You are an absolute legend my friend. you just helped me to solve an issue that I have been working on for 2 days. Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you